# ubuntu installation -ram allocation-i feel my os slow

Tags: 14.04

i am using 4GB RAM and 500 HDD. Intel i5 processor
i recently installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 and manually allocated swap space of 21 GB and extr space of 76 GB. and the system info after installation shows memory:3.8 GB and disk space:72 GB . I feel my os is slow. What should i do?

Comment: That much swap is unnecessary.

Comment: Slow is usually related to hardware drivers, most often graphics and wireless. Identify your hardware ;)

Answer (score 0):

> manually allocated swap space of 21 GB

This is  a bit of an overkill. Swap's purpose is to assist RAM, and usually the same size of swap as ram is enough, especially in your case where you have 4GB of RAM. Big swap size is necessary on machines with low ram, not in your case.

> the system info after installation shows memory:3.8 GB and disk
>   space:72 GB

Here's the thing about *nix type systems : since hard drives are divided into blocks of 512 bytes,, *nix system report size as calculated from number of those blocks. Humans think in power of 10, computers - in power of 2, so if you see your memory and hard drive space being reported somewhat different, don't be surprised. Here's an example: If I do `df -h`, where -h is human readable size (as calculated with powers of 2 ), I get 145G . With `df -H` (which is also human readable, but with powers of 10), I get 156G. The first one makes more sense from engineering / computer science point of view, because it's closer to actual, physical organization of hard drive memory. So the confusion about the size might come from the fact that installer looks at hard drive space differently than the actual installed system.

As for the ram 4 GB vs 3.8 GB, again, RAM will always be reported less, because computer science 101 tells us that there's always some reserved memory , for instance - for peripherals like keyboard, screen, etc. If the difference would be large, that's where you'd have to start worrying.

> I feel my os is slow. What should i do?

There's plenty of material on this site and others on how to improve the performance - you just need to use your googlefu a little, and as bodhi already pointed out, lag often comes from graphics. I suggest you switch from default Unity desktop to something lighter. For instance , Gnome or Cinnamon. My personal favorites are openbox, blackbox, and gnome. They're minimalistic, but they do justice to the performance.